# How to protect JSON files from being accessed by some network packet analyzer softwares like Wireshark

Tags: android, json, networking, httprequest, android-volley

I have an android application that is associated with a JSON files in cpanel , I thought that I can protect my files by setting a password to the directories but then I realised that these JSON data can be easialy catched by following http stream using WireShark , I would like to know how can I make these data unreadable by these network packet analyzer tools ?

I am using an http request & Volley Library to connect between my app and the server.

Comment: Do you have access at the server level to encrypt the data at the source and then decrypt at the client?

Comment: @Barns I don't know where can I look for that access , Im using hostgator cpanel

Comment: My point was: do you have control over how the JSON data is being generated. Do you have scripts on the server to convert your data to JSON (PHP for example)?

Comment: @Barns no I don't have the control

Comment: there is only the SSH Access manager

Comment: Ok, then my encryption at the source suggestion will not help you, sorry.

Comment: can you tell me if I get an SSL certificate to my website is it gonna help to avoid that problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure your connection is secured and there is no way someone can sniffer your network. There are some steps that have to be done from server side and from the client side.

From the server side, you need to make sure your server is secured with SSL valid certificate.

From the client side, you need to make sure you are performing all your calls over https. Also, you need to enable public key pinning which will prevent a breach of the apps secure channel by man-in-the-middle attacks.

more info: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html 
https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e

Comment: your answer is correct , that's what Im gonna do thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to turn your json into a stateless https API. Get an SSL certificate and make all your calls to your service through https and then set up something like a token or API key to access the data.

Comment: and can you clarify the API key method to access the data ? I don't know how to do it